# Ubuntu 16.04 Installation Error - Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I am getting above error when selecting any of options listed below.

- Try Ubuntu without Installing
- Instll Ubuntu

I have read many posts on this site with similar problem. But it is not helping me at all.

When I click 'C' to enter into command line. It opens GRUB command line. SUDO and UPDATE commands do not work there.

Please help me that how can I fix this issue? Ty

Comment: @Melebius, I created bootable USB using another Ubuntu 16.04 PC using 'Startup Disk Creator' application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following things and let me know if it works or not.

- Please make sure that you are installing Ubuntu 16.04.04 version instead of 16.04.01 from either bootable DVD or USB.
- If Ubuntu 16.04 is still not working, try to install Ubuntu 14.04. It worked for me in past for same error.